# How to get wandb to pass arguments by position?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wandb

I am trying to explore the results of different parameter settings on my python script "train.py". For that, I use a wandb sweep. Each wandb agent executes the file "train.py" and passes some parameters to it. As per the wandb documentation (https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/sweeps/configuration#command), in case of e.g. two parameters "param1" and "param2" each agents starts the file with the command

```
/usr/bin/env python train.py --param1=value1 --param2=value2
```

However, "train.py" expects

```
/usr/bin/env python train.py value1 value2
```

and parses the parameter values by position. I did not write train.py and would like to not change it if possible. How can I get wandb to pass the values without "--param1=" in front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you can get positional arguments from W&B Sweeps. However, there's a little work around you can try that won't require you touching the `train.py` file.

You can create an invoker file, let's call it `invoke.py`. Now, you can use it get rid of the keyword argument names. Something like this might work:

```py
import sys
import subprocess

if len(sys.argv[0]) <= 1:
  print(f"{sys.argv[0]} program_name param0=<param0> param1=<param1> ...")
  sys.exit(0)

program = sys.argv[1]
params = sys.argv[2:]

posparam = []
for param in params:
  _, val = param.split("=")
  posparam.append(val)

command = [sys.executable, program, *posparam]
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate()
sys.stdout.write(out.decode())
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stderr.write(err.decode())
sys.stderr.flush()
sys.exit(process.returncode)
```

This allows you to invoke your `train.py` file as follows:

```sh
$ python3 invoke.py /path/to/train.py param0=0.001 param1=20 ...
```

Now to perform W&B sweeps you can create a `command:` section ([reference](https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/sweeps/configuration#command)) in your `sweeps.yaml` file while sweeping over the parameters `param0` and `param1`. For example:

```yaml
program: invoke.py
...
parameters:
  param0:
    distribution: uniform
    min: 0
    max: 1
  param1:
    distribution: categorical
    values: [10, 20, 30]
command:
 - ${env}
 - ${program}
 - /path/to/train.py
 - ${args_no_hyphens}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is definetively a possibility. I will accept the answer in a few hours if there is no more direct suggestion

Comment: I don't think there is a direct way to pass positional arguments. Currently, we (I work for W&B) only support 4 different ways to pass arguments, `${args}`, `${args_no_hyphens}`, `${args_json}` and `${args_json_file}` as you might see in the reference doc [here](https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/sweeps/configuration#command).

Comment: Thank you again! Since it was expected in this other code, which I was instructed to run with wandb, I assumed that there would be some workaround, but I since found out that there are some other problems anyway, so maybe not ;)